# How to design a table grid using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table grid somthing like image as shown below:
[image]

I have also create a table but its not look like as we in image. Here's the code

```html
<table border="2" cellpadding="1">
  <tr border="1">
    <td>
      <p id="p_tit" class="p_tit">=====================================Q-05========================================</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="2" cellpadding="1">
  <tr border="1">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="p_tit3">Question</p>
      <p>1604100016</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="p_tit3">
        A train 125 m long passes a man, running at 5 km/hr in the same direction in which the train is going, in 10 seconds. The speed of the train is:
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr border="1">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="p_tit3">Options</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td id="opt">45 km/h</td>
          <td id="opt">50 km/h</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="opt">40 km/h</td>
          <td id="opt">55 km/h</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr border="1">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="p_tit3">Explanation</p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <p>
        Explanation
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and its look like 
[image]

So how can I create table look like figure 1 ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Note: When creating a snippet - there's a button labelled `Tidy` which does what it says on the tin and makes code much more readable

Comment: Add <td rowspan="3"></td>

Comment: Tables and nested tables, very bad (unless this is an email template).  Tables should not be used for layout - they should only be used for tabular data, but also why have you put `colspan=2` on every td?  If all of them have it then it's just a column, it is not spanning anything.  Also ids should be unique; and the border and cellpadding attributes have been deprecated and should not be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the attribute rowspan. I added the  to your first row in the table (and gave it 20% width that it doesn't collapse):

```
    <td rowspan="3" style="width: 20%;">          
    </td>
```

Full Table Code:

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="1">
    <tr border="1">
        <td colspan="2">
            <p id="p_tit3">Question</p>
            <p>1604100016</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p id="p_tit3"> 
                A train 125 m long passes a man, running at 5 km/hr in the same direction in which the train is going, in 10 seconds. The speed of the train is:
            </p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="3" style="width: 20%;">          
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1">
        <td colspan="2">
            <p id="p_tit3">Options</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td id="opt">45 km/h</td>
                    <td id="opt">50 km/h</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="opt">40 km/h</td>
                    <td id="opt">55 km/h</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr border="1">
        <td colspan="2">
            <p id="p_tit3">Explanation</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p>
                Explanation
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72htupn4/

Here is some documentation on rowspan: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score -1):

I use [this page](http://html-tables.com/) to generate tables in an easy way and your table seems easy to create, this is the skeleton code for your table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```